# How to wait for all items to load within ng-repeat before then rendering a chart for each item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using `ng-repeat` to show a load of report items on the page. Each item has a load of numbers so we want to show a little chart with each item.

I have set up a directive to render the chart inside each item and pass in the data to the directive. When it comes to rendering the chart however, I am relying on a button to force an update:

```
App.controller('ScoringPolarCtrl', ["$scope", function($scope){
     $scope.forceUpdate = function () {
        console.log("Attempting to render chart ID: " + itemId);
        var ctx = document.getElementById(itemId).getContext("2d");
        $scope.scoreChart = new Chart(ctx)
        $scope.scoreChart.PolarArea($scope.scoreChartData,
        $scope.itemScoreChartOptions);
     };
}]);
```

This works, but what I would like to do is somehow get the chart to render without relying on the `forceUpdate()` function.

The items are all pulled down from a web service using `$http` so it takes a few seconds for them to appear on the page and thus for the element to actually be available on the page for `chart.js` to use.

I have tried playing with `angular.element(document).ready()` to no avail. Is there any other way I can force the controller to wait until all the items are there first and then render the charts?

Comment: What if you maintain a separate array and when that's done populating you set the scope array to the "temp" array. That will then trigger the ng-repeat

Comment: If the data is being pulled down for each row as separate requests then a directive for the chart makes the most sense. The directive would download the data and upon completion would crate the chart for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place a `$watch` from your controller. Giving your items on `$scope` a name of `yourItems` in your `$http.get().then()` completion, consider the following example

```
.controller('ScoringPolarCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('yourItems', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal) {
            // render charts
        }
    });
}]);
```

You could also define a `$scope` function on your controller and call from directive within your `$http` callback. This may look different if you are isolating `$scope` or not, but here is the basic idea

```
// -- directive
$http.get('/foo').then(function(results) {
    scope.renderCharts(results); // -- async complete
});

// -- controller
$scope.renderCharts = function(results) {
    // render charts -- this is called once you receive your $http response
}
```

Comment: I'm going to have a play with both. Haven't needed to use $scope.$watch before so looking forward to trying that.

Comment: @MikeRouse excellent keep me posted with your findings and we can help work you through this

Comment: @MikeRouse were you able to solve this? Any new details on the issue?

Comment: I didn't have much luck with the $watch suggestion. oldVal and newVal were always stuck stubbornly to 'null'. I tried putting $scope.$digest() inside the else, but this complained about digest already running and then I ended up in a rabbit hole of people arguing over how to handle this. So I thought there must be an easier way for angular to pick up the element, and it turns out I could use `angular.element.find("canvas")` and then use `angular.forEach` to call my forceUpdate() method. Because I am using a directive there is only ever going to be 1 canvas element for it to find, so OK for me.

Comment: I'm surprised `$watch` didn't work how you wanted. Were you assigning a value to `$scope` in the `$http` success callback? Thats the key, say in your callback you assign `$scope.yourItems` = `response.data`, or something, Angular will "keep tabs" on `"yourItems"` and fire this function anytime that value changes. Regardless, good to hear you figured it out. Would you mind if I update my answer with your workaround? @MikeRouse

Comment: I might not be out of the woods yet. My workaround has gone nuts, keeps invoking and choking the page. I'm going to go back based on your comment as I wasn't watching those items on the basis they exist in another controller and are passed in via a directive, but I'll explore that route a bit more and come back.

Comment: aw snap!! Keep me posted @MikeRouse we'll try to get this working out for you

Comment: You were right - the key was to keep an eye in the callback, but in my case that was happening in another controller, so the quickest and easiest way I could figure it out was to stick `$rootScope.itemsLoaded = true` in the callback and then $watch out for this in my directive's controller.